# Springer's middot character

Tags: lncs, keywords

In the ["Springer Guidelines for Authors of Proceedings"](ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/svproc/guidelines/Springer_Guidelines_for_Authors_of_Proceedings.pdf), I found that:

> Keywords: Please list your keywords here. They should be separated by middots, if possible. ...

So I assume that the LaTeX source should look like

```
\keywords{keyword1 \middot keyword2 \middot ... }
```

What is the magic `\middot` here? Note that I made up the `\middot` command here and I am actually looking for a correct latex command to substitute it.

I would like to avoid `$\cdot$` and I tried `\textperiodcentered` bud then there is no space between the dot and the following keyword. And typing `\textperiodcentered~` also seems rather cumbersome.

Can anyone suggest what LaTeX command is expected? Surprisingly, I was not able to find it in Springer's documentation.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\textperiodcenter{}` will do

Comment: There is no reference to `\middot` in `llncs.cls`.

Comment: Create your own macro in the preamble. `\def\middot{\textperiodcentered~}` should do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example is found in a sample file that comes along with the author kit for some conference:

`\keywords{First keyword  \and Second keyword \and Another keyword}`

This should result in a list of keywords separated by 'middots' as long as you use the llncs class file.

Answer (score 2):

Recently, I was asked to confirm my paper in Springer (office in India). The typesetter has corrected the keywords separator from comma to so-called middle dot, see in UTF `U+00B7`. This symbol was inputted directly as utf symbol, you can simply copy it from here `·` into your tex-file.

One can check the UTF code of a symbol in the internet, e.g. [here](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html). The detailed discussion about dots in Latex is given [on this web-page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19180/which-dot-character-to-use-in-which-context).